# JavaScript heap out of memory in Docker image run

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

Usually I run my application as **`npm run dev`**  and in the package.json file has script like below

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    }
```

here everything working fine.

I'm build docker image based on below Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17-alpine

RUN npm i -g typescript@4.2.4


RUN npm i -g nodemon

RUN apk add g++ make python


WORKDIR /app 

ADD package*.json ./

RUN npm install

ADD . .

CMD npm run dev
```

I can able to successfully build the image using

```
 docker build --tag test-backend .
```

and when I this image

```
docker run  -it -p 3003:3003 test-backend
```

I'm facing javascript heap memory outage

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[31:0x55effca3d8e0]    57856 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 989.3 (996.6) -> 988.2 (997.9) MB, 1275.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.173, current mu = 0.035) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[31:0x55effca3d8e0]    59100 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 989.3 (999.9) -> 988.5 (999.4) MB, 1206.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.107, current mu = 0.030) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Aborted
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

what is the reason behing this cause ??

Answer (score 37):

I am trying to fix the same problem. Basically, the problem comes because the process is getting more memory allowed by the system. For example, if your machine has 2GB of memory, the process overloads the memory available.

This kind of problem, I solved by adding a swap file to the machine to help a bit the memory (Maybe this article can help you: https://tecadmin.net/linux-create-swap/) and, setup this env `ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048` in your `Dockerfile` to limit the memory will be used by the node process.

Instead of `2048`, use the same value as a memory you have in your machine.

This setting works for me. I hope these comments can help you.

Comment: This worked! TY SO MUCHH

Comment: This worked! You saved my date

Comment: By the way, the unit for `max_old_space_size` [is megabytes](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes) :)

Answer (score 9):

For Mac users out there! After I add below directives for the environment variables, I needed to increase from GUI (swap and memory):

```bash
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=16384
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---- For non linux users ( Windows specifically ) ----

Add

```
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

in your docker file.
This worked for me.

Thanks!